# dividing the values of data.table1 by data.table2 in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have created two fictional `data.tables` which summarise the `cost` and `count` of the items that contributed to the cost. I would like to calculate the average item cost = cost/count.

**How can i divide the values of the two data.tables ?**

```
combi_sum <- dcast(merge(mtcarsTOTAL[,.(cost, gear)], iris[, .N, .(carb, gear, gender, age)], by = "gear"), 
                gender + age ~ carb, value.var = "cost", fun.aggregate = sum, fill = 0)

structure(list(gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), age = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), `1` = c(978, 978, 0, 0, 1074, 0, 0, 
0, 2642, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3620, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 978, 0, 
0, 978, 2052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 978, 0, 0, 0, 3620, 0), `2` = c(0, 
0, 0, 978, 0, 0, 0, 2052, 0, 2642, 978, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1074, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 0, 978, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 
978, 2642), `3` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 
2642, 978, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 3620, 2642, 0, 0, 
0, 978, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 2642, 0, 2642, 0, 0), `4` = c(0, 0, 1074, 
0, 0, 0, 978, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 1074, 0, 2052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 
0, 2642, 1074, 978, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 2642, 0, 2052, 0, 2642, 
1074, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb24d802ee0>, sorted = c("gender", 
"age"))

combi_length <- dcast(merge(mtcarsTOTAL[,.(cost, gear)], iris[, .N, .(carb, gear, gender, age)], by = "gear"), 
                   gender + age ~ carb, value.var = "cost", fun.aggregate = length, fill = 0)

structure(list(gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), age = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), `1` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), `2` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), `3` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `4` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb24d802ee0>, sorted = c("gender", 
"age"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
combi_sum[combi_length, as.character(1L:4L) := {
    m <- unlist(mget(paste0("x.", 1L:4L))) / unlist(mget(paste0("i.", 1L:4L)))
    as.data.table(matrix(replace(m, is.nan(m), 0), nrow=.N))
}]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
combi_sum <- 
structure(list(gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), age = c(1L, 2L, 
        3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
        9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), `1` = c(978, 978, 0, 0, 1074, 0, 0, 
            0, 2642, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3620, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 978, 0, 
            0, 978, 2052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 978, 0, 0, 0, 3620, 0), `2` = c(0, 
                0, 0, 978, 0, 0, 0, 2052, 0, 2642, 978, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                1074, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 0, 978, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 
                978, 2642), `3` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 
                    2642, 978, 0, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 3620, 2642, 0, 0, 
                    0, 978, 0, 2642, 0, 0, 2642, 0, 2642, 0, 0), `4` = c(0, 0, 1074, 
                        0, 0, 0, 978, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 1074, 0, 2052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 
                        0, 2642, 1074, 978, 978, 2642, 0, 0, 2642, 0, 2052, 0, 2642, 
                        1074, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("data.table", 
                            "data.frame"))
setDT(combi_sum, key=c("gender", "age"))

combi_length <- structure(list(gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), age = c(1L, 2L, 
        3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
        9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), `1` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
            1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), `2` = c(0L, 
                0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                0L, 1L, 1L), `3` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `4` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
                        0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                        1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                        0L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                        ))
setDT(combi_length, key=c("gender", "age"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but to divide values of one data.frame by another in R - you literally just divide them.  I've created an example dataset to show you:

```
t1 <- data.frame(A1=c(10,2,4,1,4), B1=c(5,1,8,9,4), C1=c(12,10,10,5,1))
t2 <- data.frame(A2=c(8,2,5,10,1), B2=c(5,6,8,9,1), C2=c(6,5,15,10,12))
```

To divide t2/t1, you just do that:

```
t2/t1
```

Giving you:

```
     A2   B2   C2
1  0.80 1.00  0.5
2  1.00 6.00  0.5
3  1.25 1.00  1.5
4 10.00 1.00  2.0
5  0.25 0.25 12.0
```

Basically, this can be understood as `t1[x,y]/t2[x,y]`, giving you the answer dataset as `t3[x,y]`.  Make sense?  Is that what you were asking?